# Jenkins docker build No such directory error

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

i am trying to build a docker image with jenkins bbut i keep getting **ADD failed: no source files were specified** error but it builds when using the command line.

my pipeline script is below:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        dockerImage=''

    }
    tools {
        // Install the Maven version configured as "M3" and add it to the path.
        maven "maven3"
  
    }

    stages {
        stage('Clone') {
            steps {
                // Get some code from a GitHub repository
                git branch: 'main', credentialsId: '9e078e67-9fad-43ca-b0c5-feadb03fc060', poll: false, url: 'https://github.com/phelumie/Birthday-Scheduling-App.git'
            }
            
        }
        
        stage('Build jar') {
            steps {
                sh "mvn -f scheduler/pom.xml package -DskipTests -X"
                echo 'Build jar Completed' 
            }
        }

        stage('Build image') {
            steps {
                
            echo 'Starting to build docker image'
                script {
def  dockerImage=docker.build("phelumiess/demo","-f scheduler/Dockerfile .")
                    echo 'Build Image Completed' 
            }
            }
        }

    }
    
    
}
```

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine 
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/birthday-scheduler*.jar birthday-scheduler.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/birthday-scheduler.jar" ]
```

Comment: The issue was that my project is in a sub directory so i had to prefix my add statement with the name of the directory like FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine EXPOSE 8080 ADD scheduler/target/birthday-scheduler*.jar birthday-scheduler.jar ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/birthday-scheduler.jar" ]

Answer (score 0):

Change the directory before executing the docker build command. Refer the following.

```json
stage('Build image') {
      steps {
            echo 'Starting to build docker image'
              dir('Birthday-Scheduling-App/scheduler') {
                script {
                    def  dockerImage=docker.build("phelumiess/demo")
                    echo 'Build Image Completed' 
                }
            }
        }
}
```